# Using 2 FROM in docker file: alpine-java-python and python3 removes installed java?

Tags: java, python-3.x, docker, alpine-linux

In my project, I need java and python3.
I used 2 FROM statements in Dockerfile.

```
FROM docker.<xx>.com/alpine-java-python
......
......
FROM python3
......
......
CMD [ "java", "-jar", "abc.jar"]
```

On starting of the container it gives "java command not found".
Why does the installed java gets deleted when using FROM python3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to answer your question of why the installed Java gets deleted when using 'FROM python3':

The [Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from) states:

> FROM can appear multiple times within a single Dockerfile to create multiple images or use one build stage as a dependency for another...Each FROM instruction clears any state created by previous instructions.

So what's happening is that your second 'FROM' is writing over what was done in the first 'FROM' and that's why you don't see Java in the final image.

Now, to answer the implied question of how do you fix this...

Since you want to have all these packages in a single image, you need to either:

1. Add the packages within a single 'FROM' section or
2. Use multi-stage docker builds where you pull packages installed, built, etc. from one 'FROM' instruction into another 'FROM' instruction.  If you want to use multi-staged builds, I recommend reading the [Docker Documentation on multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

For the example here, option (1) is sufficient.  For that case, you should be able to do something like the following:

```
FROM docker.<xx>.com/alpine-java-python
RUN apk update && apk add python3
......
......
......
......
CMD [ "java", "-jar", "abc.jar"]
```

---

Note that if python2 exists in the base image, then both versions will now be installed and you will want to reference the python3 version when running your application, or change the default version.